# How to handle ajaxSetup binding for all elements instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have AJAX event binding on my layout page:

```
$(document).not("#approvalTitleBlock").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
  $("#loading").show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

This is not triggered on `ajaxSend`. However if I replace it with this then it works correctly:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() {
  $("#loading").show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Why do I have this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it's a global AJAX event handler. It is not raised on the element you selected, in fact it's not raised on any DOM element. It's only raised on the `document` itself. See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend):

> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the `ajaxSend()` method, must be attached to `document`.

*Update*

Based on your comment below:

> I want to change behavior for events on `ajaxSend` and `ajaxStop` for AJAX call on `#approvalTitleBlock` (it shouldn't show `#loading`)

In this case add the `global: false` property to the `$.ajax()` settings when you make the request. This will prevent any global handlers being invoked for the request.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, or why you you would want to do that. An AJAX request is not related to any element, so how could it resolve to that?

Comment: I want to change behavior for events on ajaxSend and ajaxStop for AJAX call on #approvalTitleBlock block (it shouldn't show #loading) If you understand what I mean

Comment: In that case use the `global: false` property in the `$.ajax()` setting for that request. There's no way to relate a global event to an element after it has fired.